# I am getting class not found exception while implementing Page factory model in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
  I am implementing page factory model for testing. For 1st Test case, i am getting above error. Please help me regarding the same. It is telling "Cannot inject @Test annotated Method  with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]."
```

I have one class with name Home and another TestCase class citing Home class for web element and being used for passing arguments.

```
  [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.10.0
    [TestNG] Running:
      C:\Users\ue\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1220071011\testng-customsuite.xml

    [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
    Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [verifyLoginWithInvalidCredentials] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].
    For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
```

Comment: Are trying to use this with Angular ?

Comment: Did you initialized the page using PageFactory? If you already done this then it will be better that you also share the code of your test and page object so we can help you better.